# What is 'required from here' error

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw

It is in my Eclipse Problems view. The code compiles fine but there is an error saying "`required from here`", pointing to some boost header file and to the line `state_data const current_state=interlocked_compare_exchange(&state,new_state,old_state);`

I don't like to have errors or warnings. Does anybody know what that is?

Comment: It's only a part of the error message, telling you where the error is coming from.

Comment: It usually says *something very long* and adds "required from here" part to help figure out what code *caused* that *something* to happen. Showing the rest of the message might help.

Comment: It is the only thing in errors section and the code compiles fine. There are only warnings after it in console output.

Comment: Eclipse is taking part of a warning and displaying it in the error section.  Get rid of all your warnings and it should go away.

Comment: You should always fix issues from the first message to the last (as produced by the compiler, not as digested and spewed by the IDE). Take a look at the output from the compiler and it will become simple(/simpleR) to understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behavior is a bug of eclipse CDT Error Parser: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=108720
Actually this error is a warning and boost is responsible for it. You can disable this special kind of warnings to omit them.

Comment: how to disable it..I get this bug every time I run the NDK in Eclipse

Comment: Depending on your warning that is coursing the problem you can disable it with `-w`. See [gcc warning doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) on how to disable warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually returned? and check the types &state new_state and old_state.
if you used: int new_state; and in the function compare_exchange(size_t &state, size_t new_state, size_t old_state)
You get this error, well i did :)

```
          state_data const current_state = interlocked_compare_exchange(&state,new_state,old_state);
```

add:

```
      return new_state;
```