# How to solve ambiguity in operator overloading embedded inside a struct?

Tags: c++, struct, set, operator-overloading

In the following code, the g++ compiler surprisingly cannot decide which operator to use when they are embedded in a struct to serve as a comparator argument in a set:

```
#include <string>
#include <set>

struct KeyWord {
  std::string str;
  int qt;
  KeyWord(const std::string aKw = "", const int aQt = 0) : str(aKw), qt(aQt) {}
};

struct CompareKeywords {
  bool operator() (const std::string& left, const std::string& right) const {
    if (left.size() > right.size()) return true;
    else if (left.size() < right.size()) return false;
    else return (left < right);
  }
  bool operator() (const KeyWord& left, const KeyWord& right) {
    if (left.str.size() > right.str.size()) return true;
    else if (left.str.size() < right.str.size()) return false;
    else return (left.str < right.str);
  }
};

int main() {
  std::set<std::string, CompareKeywords> a;
  std::set<KeyWord, CompareKeywords> b;
  std::string s("_s_");
  KeyWord k("_k_", 1);
  a.insert(s);
  b.insert(k);
}
```

Here is the compiler output:

```
g++ oa.cpp
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_tree.h: In instantiation of ‘std::pair<std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*> std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_get_insert_unique_pos(const key_type&) [with _Key = std::basic_string<char>; _Val = std::basic_string<char>; _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity<std::basic_string<char> >; _Compare = CompareKeywords; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = std::basic_string<char>]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_tree.h:1498:47:   required from ‘std::pair<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<_Val>, bool> std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_insert_unique(const _Val&) [with _Key = std::basic_string<char>; _Val = std::basic_string<char>; _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity<std::basic_string<char> >; _Compare = CompareKeywords; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> >]’
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_set.h:502:29:   required from ‘std::pair<typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Key, std::_Identity<_Key>, _Compare, typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::rebind<_Key>::other>::const_iterator, bool> std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(const value_type&) [with _Key = std::basic_string<char>; _Compare = CompareKeywords; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> >; typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Key, std::_Identity<_Key>, _Compare, typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::rebind<_Key>::other>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::basic_string<char> >; std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type = std::basic_string<char>]’
oa.cpp:28:13:   required from here
oa.cpp:11:8: note: candidate 1: bool CompareKeywords::operator()(const string&, const string&) const
   bool operator() (const std::string& left, const std::string& right) const {
        ^
oa.cpp:16:8: note: candidate 2: bool CompareKeywords::operator()(const KeyWord&, const KeyWord&)
   bool operator() (const KeyWord& left, const KeyWord& right) {
        ^
oa.cpp:11:8: note: candidate 1: bool CompareKeywords::operator()(const string&, const string&) const
   bool operator() (const std::string& left, const std::string& right) const {
        ^
oa.cpp:16:8: note: candidate 2: bool CompareKeywords::operator()(const KeyWord&, const KeyWord&)
   bool operator() (const KeyWord& left, const KeyWord& right) {
        ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_tree.h: In instantiation of ‘std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_insert_(std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Base_ptr, std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Base_ptr, const _Val&) [with _Key = std::basic_string<char>; _Val = std::basic_string<char>; _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity<std::basic_string<char> >; _Compare = CompareKeywords; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::basic_string<char> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Base_ptr = std::_Rb_tree_node_base*]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_tree.h:1502:38:   required from ‘std::pair<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<_Val>, bool> std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_insert_unique(const _Val&) [with _Key = std::basic_string<char>; _Val = std::basic_string<char>; _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity<std::basic_string<char> >; _Compare = CompareKeywords; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> >]’
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_set.h:502:29:   required from ‘std::pair<typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Key, std::_Identity<_Key>, _Compare, typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::rebind<_Key>::other>::const_iterator, bool> std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(const value_type&) [with _Key = std::basic_string<char>; _Compare = CompareKeywords; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> >; typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Key, std::_Identity<_Key>, _Compare, typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::rebind<_Key>::other>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::basic_string<char> >; std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type = std::basic_string<char>]’
oa.cpp:28:13:   required from here
oa.cpp:11:8: note: candidate 1: bool CompareKeywords::operator()(const string&, const string&) const
   bool operator() (const std::string& left, const std::string& right) const {
        ^
oa.cpp:16:8: note: candidate 2: bool CompareKeywords::operator()(const KeyWord&, const KeyWord&)
   bool operator() (const KeyWord& left, const KeyWord& right) {
        ^
```

The last lines show the ambiguity where the compiler shows two candidates.

Why this ambiguity exist? How should I supress it?

Comment: I don't see the word "ambiguous" or anything like it in the text you posted. It looks like you edited out the key parts. But as a guess, the second one is not `const`, and that might be confusing things.

Comment: @Pete Becker I just tested it and you're exactly right: It looks like the compiler can't decide between adding const to the comparison object member with an exact string parameter match vs implicitly creating a `Keyword` from a string and having an exact function-const match.

Comment: Making the second `operator()` `const` eliminates the messages in this example.

Comment: @PeteBecker I was sure of the same (somebody/something is editing out key parts) but no, [it's real](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c005ed1d3f1a3e9). Looks like a bug in gcc. Not all gcc builds do that,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like *some builds* of gcc have this peculiar feature of printing these messages out of the blue. For example all builds on coliru [do this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c005ed1d3f1a3e9).

These messages are not errors because the object file is produced, and they are not warnings because `-Werror` doesn't turn them into errors. They look rather like a compiler bug. Obviously one cannot suppress these non-warnings with compiler flags.

Same exact versions of `gcc` on my machine don't print any messages with *this* code. They do print regular (tagged with the coloured "warning", non-suppressible, but turnable-to-error) warnings with [similar code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41383756/775806).

On coliru, making the second `operator()` `const` [suppresses the messages](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d3fc0323323f806).

Answer (score 0):

Two separate `struct` with only one operator in each of them dedicated to a type solves the problem:

```
#include <string>
#include <set>

struct KeyWord {
  std::string str;
  int qt;
  KeyWord(const std::string aKw = "", const int aQt = 0) : str(aKw), qt(aQt) {}
};

struct CompareStrings {
  bool operator() (const std::string& left, const std::string& right) const {
    if (left.size() > right.size()) return true;
    else if (left.size() < right.size()) return false;
    else return (left < right);
  }
};
struct CompareKeywords {
   bool operator() (const KeyWord& left, const KeyWord& right) {
    if (left.str.size() > right.str.size()) return true;
    else if (left.str.size() < right.str.size()) return false;
    else return (left.str < right.str);
  }
};

int main() {
  std::set<std::string, CompareStrings> a;
  std::set<KeyWord, CompareKeywords> b;
  std::string s("_s_");
  KeyWord k("_k_", 1);
  a.insert(s);
  b.insert(k);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There was an error in the initial code:

```
  bool operator() (const std::string& left, const std::string& right) const {
  bool operator() (const KeyWord& left, const KeyWord& right) {
```

Suppressing the `const` at the end of the first declaration, or adding one to the second one solves the problem. But still, I don't understand why the compiler was confused.

So, either:

```
  bool operator() (const std::string& left, const std::string& right) {
  bool operator() (const KeyWord& left, const KeyWord& right) {
```

or:

```
  bool operator() (const std::string& left, const std::string& right) const {
  bool operator() (const KeyWord& left, const KeyWord& right) const {
```

works.

Note: Wheither a `const` function or not is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141087/what-is-meant-with-const-at-end-of-function-declaration).

Since I want overloading, both functions are expected to have the same behaviour, so `const` to both or none. If I would have liked different behaviours with one with `const` and the other without (in the case I would have had some `struct` members I would have wanted to modify), the second solution below with separate `struct` for each operator definition would be the solution.